# Including outside the root on heart internet servers

Tags: php, include

I have a site I am trying to deploy with includes outside the site root, on heart internet hosting. I've having difficulty including the files outside the root (above public_html). The path is something like

```
include "home/barbadosholidaylettings.org/demoinclude/core.php";
```

But I can't retrieve the files I need. Does anyone know the correct path for this on Heart Internet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved

The correct path was : ../../demoinclude/

And there was an underlying ftp problem that prevented it working before.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure sure about Heart Internet but with my hosting public_html is transparent.

so instead of browing to

www.domain.com/public_html/blah

i'd browse to

www.domain.com/blah

A collegue uses heart internet and says their online support is really good, it might be worth getting in touch with them directly via their website.